# How does the object-relational model work?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, object-relational-model

Can anyone please explain about how ORMs like hibernate work. how objects are mapped with database tables and how inheritance and other properties are managed with tables association and other database relations.

Comment: Reading the architecture document of your favorite ORM framework should help. I hate ORM frameworks.

Comment: Quoting the Help Center: `If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.` This question should be closed as Too Broad.

Comment: 600 characters is too restricted but Gavin King and Christian Bauer did it in roughly as many pages (excluding appendices) in _Java Persistence with Hibernate_ (Manning).

Comment: I don't know why this question is down voted. It may be long to answer but it's not unconstructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about some brain friendly materials for beginners try this youtube channel:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yv2xctJxE-w

PS. That is not a spam. This is not my channel.